# System halts for a fraction of second after every 2-3 seconds

Tags: windows-7, performance, halts

I'm using Windows 7 on my HP ProBook 4250s. The problem I face is that my system halts for a fraction of second after every 2-3 seconds. These jerks are not letting me concentrate or work properly. This happens even when I'm just typing in notepad while no other application is running. I tried to install every driver from HP's website and there's no item in device manager marked with yellow icon.

**Following are my system specs:**

Machine: HP ProBook 4250s
OS: Windows 7 professional
RAM: 2GB
Processor: Intel Core i3 2.27GHz

Following is my HijackThis Log:

```
**Logfile of HijackThis v1.99.1**

Scan saved at 9:34:03 PM, on 11/13/2012
Platform: Unknown Windows (WinNT 6.01.3504)
MSIE: Internet Explorer v9.00 (9.00.8112.16450)

**Running processes:**

C:\Windows\system32\taskhost.exe
C:\Windows\System32\rundll32.exe
C:\Windows\system32\Dwm.exe
C:\Windows\Explorer.EXE
C:\Windows\System32\igfxtray.exe
C:\Windows\System32\hkcmd.exe
C:\Windows\System32\igfxpers.exe
C:\Program Files\Synaptics\SynTP\SynTPEnh.exe
C:\Program Files\PowerISO\PWRISOVM.EXE
C:\Program Files\AVAST Software\Avast\AvastUI.exe
C:\Program Files\Free Download Manager\fdm.exe
C:\Windows\system32\wuauclt.exe
C:\Program Files\Windows Media Player\wmplayer.exe
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office12\WINWORD.EXE
C:\HijackThis\HijackThis.exe

R1 - HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main,Search Page = http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=54896
R0 - HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main,Start Page = http://bing.com/
R1 - HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main,Default_Page_URL = http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=69157
R1 - HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main,Default_Search_URL = http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=54896
R1 - HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main,Search Page = http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=54896
R0 - HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main,Start Page = http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=69157
R0 - HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Search,SearchAssistant = 
R0 - HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Search,CustomizeSearch = 
R0 - HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Toolbar,LinksFolderName = 
R3 - URLSearchHook: (no name) - {7473b6bd-4691-4744-a82b-7854eb3d70b6} - (no file)
O2 - BHO: Adobe PDF Reader Link Helper - {06849E9F-C8D7-4D59-B87D-784B7D6BE0B3} - C:\Program Files\Common Files\Adobe\Acrobat\ActiveX\AcroIEHelper.dll
O2 - BHO: Babylon toolbar helper - {2EECD738-5844-4a99-B4B6-146BF802613B} - (no file)
O2 - BHO: MrFroggy - {856E12B5-22D7-4E22-9ACA-EA9A008DD65B} - C:\Program Files\Minibar\Froggy.dll
O2 - BHO: avast! WebRep - {8E5E2654-AD2D-48bf-AC2D-D17F00898D06} - C:\Program Files\AVAST Software\Avast\aswWebRepIE.dll
O2 - BHO: Windows Live ID Sign-in Helper - {9030D464-4C02-4ABF-8ECC-5164760863C6} - C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live\WindowsLiveLogin.dll
O2 - BHO: Minibar BHO - {AA74D58F-ACD0-450D-A85E-6C04B171C044} - C:\Program Files\Minibar\Kango.dll
O2 - BHO: Free Download Manager - {CC59E0F9-7E43-44FA-9FAA-8377850BF205} - C:\Program Files\Free Download Manager\iefdm2.dll
O2 - BHO: HP Network Check Helper - {E76FD755-C1BA-4DCB-9F13-99BD91223ADE} - C:\Program Files\Hewlett-Packard\HP Support Framework\Resources\HPNetworkCheck\HPNetworkCheckPlugin.dll
O3 - Toolbar: (no name) - {98889811-442D-49dd-99D7-DC866BE87DBC} - (no file)
O3 - Toolbar: avast! WebRep - {8E5E2654-AD2D-48bf-AC2D-D17F00898D06} - C:\Program Files\AVAST Software\Avast\aswWebRepIE.dll
O4 - HKLM\..\Run: [IgfxTray] C:\Windows\system32\igfxtray.exe
O4 - HKLM\..\Run: [HotKeysCmds] C:\Windows\system32\hkcmd.exe
O4 - HKLM\..\Run: [Persistence] C:\Windows\system32\igfxpers.exe
O4 - HKLM\..\Run: [SynTPEnh] %ProgramFiles%\Synaptics\SynTP\SynTPEnh.exe
O4 - HKLM\..\Run: [PWRISOVM.EXE] C:\Program Files\PowerISO\PWRISOVM.EXE -startup
O4 - HKLM\..\Run: [AdobeAAMUpdater-1.0] "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Adobe\OOBE\PDApp\UWA\UpdaterStartupUtility.exe"
O4 - HKLM\..\Run: [AdobeCS6ServiceManager] "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Adobe\CS6ServiceManager\CS6ServiceManager.exe" -launchedbylogin
O4 - HKLM\..\Run: [SwitchBoard] C:\Program Files\Common Files\Adobe\SwitchBoard\SwitchBoard.exe
O4 - HKLM\..\Run: [ROC_roc_ssl_v12] "C:\Program Files\AVG Secure Search\ROC_roc_ssl_v12.exe" / /PROMPT /CMPID=roc_ssl_v12
O4 - HKLM\..\Run: [avast] "C:\Program Files\AVAST Software\Avast\avastUI.exe" /nogui
O4 - HKLM\..\Run: [Wordinn English to Urdu Dictionary] "C:\Program Files\Wordinn\Urdu Dictionary\bin\Lugat.exe" -h
O4 - HKLM\..\Run: [Adobe Reader Speed Launcher] "C:\Program Files\Adobe\Reader 8.0\Reader\Reader_sl.exe"
O4 - HKCU\..\Run: [Comparator Fast] "C:\Program Files\Interdesigner Software\Comparator Fast\ComparatorFast.exe"  /STARTUP
O4 - HKCU\..\Run: [Free Download Manager] "C:\Program Files\Free Download Manager\fdm.exe" -autorun
O8 - Extra context menu item: Download all with Free Download Manager - file://C:\Program Files\Free Download Manager\dlall.htm
O8 - Extra context menu item: Download selected with Free Download Manager - file://C:\Program Files\Free Download Manager\dlselected.htm
O8 - Extra context menu item: Download video with Free Download Manager - file://C:\Program Files\Free Download Manager\dlfvideo.htm
O8 - Extra context menu item: Download with Free Download Manager - file://C:\Program Files\Free Download Manager\dllink.htm
O8 - Extra context menu item: E&xport to Microsoft Excel - res://C:\PROGRA~1\MICROS~2\Office12\EXCEL.EXE/3000
O9 - Extra button: @C:\Program Files\Hewlett-Packard\HP Support Framework\Resources\HPNetworkCheck\HPNetworkCheckPlugin.dll,-103 - {25510184-5A38-4A99-B273-DCA8EEF6CD08} - C:\Program Files\Hewlett-Packard\HP Support Framework\Resources\HPNetworkCheck\NCLauncherFromIE.exe
O9 - Extra 'Tools' menuitem: @C:\Program Files\Hewlett-Packard\HP Support Framework\Resources\HPNetworkCheck\HPNetworkCheckPlugin.dll,-102 - {25510184-5A38-4A99-B273-DCA8EEF6CD08} - C:\Program Files\Hewlett-Packard\HP Support Framework\Resources\HPNetworkCheck\NCLauncherFromIE.exe
O9 - Extra button: Research - {92780B25-18CC-41C8-B9BE-3C9C571A8263} - C:\PROGRA~1\MICROS~2\Office12\REFIEBAR.DLL
O9 - Extra button: Change your facebook look - {AAA38851-3CFF-475F-B5E0-720D3645E4A5} - C:\Program Files\Minibar\MinibarButton.dll
O10 - Unknown file in Winsock LSP: c:\windows\system32\nlaapi.dll
O10 - Unknown file in Winsock LSP: c:\windows\system32\napinsp.dll
O10 - Unknown file in Winsock LSP: c:\program files\common files\microsoft shared\windows live\wlidnsp.dll
O10 - Unknown file in Winsock LSP: c:\program files\common files\microsoft shared\windows live\wlidnsp.dll
O11 - Options group: [ACCELERATED_GRAPHICS] Accelerated graphics
O11 - Options group: [INTERNATIONAL] International
O13 - Gopher Prefix: 
O17 - HKLM\System\CCS\Services\Tcpip\..\{920289D7-5F75-4181-9A37-5627EAA163E3}: NameServer = 8.8.8.8,8.8.4.4
O17 - HKLM\System\CCS\Services\Tcpip\..\{AE83ED2F-EF14-4066-ACE2-C4ED07A68EAA}: NameServer = 9.9.9.9,8.8.8.8
O18 - Protocol: ms-help - {314111C7-A502-11D2-BBCA-00C04F8EC294} - C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Help\hxds.dll
O18 - Protocol: skype4com - {FFC8B962-9B40-4DFF-9458-1830C7DD7F5D} - C:\PROGRA~1\COMMON~1\Skype\SKYPE4~1.DLL
O18 - Protocol: wlpg - {E43EF6CD-A37A-4A9B-9E6F-83F89B8E6324} - C:\Program Files\Windows Live\Photo Gallery\AlbumDownloadProtocolHandler.dll
O18 - Filter hijack: text/xml - {807563E5-5146-11D5-A672-00B0D022E945} - C:\PROGRA~1\COMMON~1\MICROS~1\OFFICE12\MSOXMLMF.DLL
O20 - AppInit_DLLs: c:\progra~2\browse~1\23787~1.43\{16cdf~1\browse~1.dll c:\progra~2\browse~1\22630~1.40\{16cdf~1\browse~1.dll
O20 - Winlogon Notify: igfxcui - C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\igfxdev.dll
O23 - Service: avast! Antivirus - AVAST Software - C:\Program Files\AVAST Software\Avast\AvastSvc.exe
O23 - Service: Google Software Updater (gusvc) - Google - C:\Program Files\Google\Common\Google Updater\GoogleUpdaterService.exe
O23 - Service: HP Support Assistant Service - Hewlett-Packard Company - C:\Program Files\Hewlett-Packard\HP Support Framework\hpsa_service.exe
O23 - Service: HP Quick Synchronization Service (HPDrvMntSvc.exe) - Hewlett-Packard Company - C:\Program Files\Hewlett-Packard\Shared\HPDrvMntSvc.exe
O23 - Service: HP Software Framework Service (hpqwmiex) - Hewlett-Packard Company - C:\Program Files\Hewlett-Packard\Shared\hpqWmiEx.exe
O23 - Service: HP Service (hpsrv) - Hewlett-Packard Company - C:\Windows\system32\Hpservice.exe
O23 - Service: Intel(R) Management and Security Application Local Management Service (LMS) - Intel Corporation - C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\LMS\LMS.exe
O23 - Service: Mozilla Maintenance Service (MozillaMaintenance) - Mozilla Foundation - C:\Program Files\Mozilla Maintenance Service\maintenanceservice.exe
O23 - Service: @%SystemRoot%\system32\qwave.dll,-1 (QWAVE) - Unknown owner - %windir%\system32\svchost.exe (file missing)
O23 - Service: @%SystemRoot%\system32\seclogon.dll,-7001 (seclogon) - Unknown owner - %windir%\system32\svchost.exe (file missing)
O23 - Service: Skype Updater (SkypeUpdate) - Skype Technologies - C:\Program Files\Skype\Updater\Updater.exe
O23 - Service: Adobe SwitchBoard (SwitchBoard) - Adobe Systems Incorporated - C:\Program Files\Common Files\Adobe\SwitchBoard\SwitchBoard.exe
O23 - Service: Intel(R) Management & Security Application User Notification Service (UNS) - Intel Corporation - C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\UNS\UNS.exe
O23 - Service: @%PROGRAMFILES%\Windows Media Player\wmpnetwk.exe,-101 (WMPNetworkSvc) - Unknown owner - %PROGRAMFILES%\Windows Media Player\wmpnetwk.exe (file missing)
```

Comment: This indicates your hdd might be failing.  Check the S.M.A.R.T data on it.

Comment: Use the Windows Event Viewer and look for System and Application error or warning entries after it's happened.

Comment: Does your computer automatically connect to a wireless network?